# How to prevent custom batch commands from closing after execution

Tags: windows, batch-file, customization

I became interested in adding custom commands to my batch programs. I created a folder in my C: drive, altered the path, and now any batch that is in the file can be called by typing its name in a script.

But for some reason, **after I type a custom command, the command executes, then ends the program altogether, even if there is more commands below it, or if there is a pause.**

I've tried altering the batch with the custom command, but to no avail.
Is there something I can do to stop this from happening?

Edit:
For example:

Below is the contents of the custom command file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

Since I modified the PATH variable in my system settings, I can type the name of the file in a script and run it as a command like so:

cecho color "text"

However, after execution, the custom command ends both itself and the script
that ran it, not allowing for any other commands after it to run.

Ex:
cecho 07 "hi" - runs then closes both processes

pause - is not run

I'm terrible at explaining things, but I hope someone understands this.

Comment: Please provide your code..

Comment: Your sample batch file doesn't have a pause command so it can't pause.  Having a cmd window open for the duration of the batch file and close when the script ends is the usual behaviour.  If you place a `pause` above the `goto :eof` in your sample script then it should wait before closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `call BatchFileName` to force the batch interpreter to return to the previous batch file.

Comment: Sorry, could you give an example?

Comment: @Noline - This is batch 101 stuff. Your "custom command" is fine. It is your script that calls the custom command that is incorrect. Simply put CALL before each custom command. Without CALL, it acts more like a GOTO (never returns). With CALL, it acts like a procedure that returns.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've never used call and such before, so this is new to me.